# cross site collection multi list view webpart

Tags: cross-list

I was able to implement this cross site collection list view webpart (link below). But know I'm currently modifying it so that I can pull from multiple lists. although, this is turning out to be more difficult than I thought. If you have any good resources that do not include a third party software, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ramg/implementing-a-simple-cross-site-collection-list-view-webpart)

Answer (score 1):

You could always try using **Search** to meet this requirement.This will depend on you being able to create a fixed query which returns only the results you require and the results will not be 'real-time' but instead dependent upon the frequency of your crawl. I [wrote a post](http://www.glynblogs.com/2009/07/how-to-do-cross-site-collection-aggregation.html) about this a while ago if it helps.

Comment: this is the the way to go, cross site and cross list really compete with each others in their primary intent. Another option is to write code that uses a cross site query for each of the sites that returned in your web part and combining these results. Although this would be pretty ineffecient as opposed to search.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for third party solutions which you can buy, check the link below:
http://www.lightningtools.com/pages/lightning-conductor-web-part.aspx

Comment: thanks but i'm looking for a solution i can implement without a third party tool.